# Replacing InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, safari, svg, rendering

I have a HTML file, which is then calling a javascript file. Basic function of the javascript file is to draw a svg file, and do modifications on it. for example

I am embedding the svg image in my JS file like this

```
this.my_object.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="img/gauge.png" width="122" height="127"/><g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)"><circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/></g><text id="value" x="35" y="103" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text></svg>';
```

Now, according to this post 
[Safari embeded SVG doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372695/safari-embeded-svg-doctype?rq=1)

I cant inline svg image because then it wont work on safari. Now due to certain restrictions I cant embed svg file in html, **it has to be accessed through javascript**. Is there any way svg image can be used in javascript without using `innerHTML`, **as finally the image has to be renedered on safari.**

PS: This image has to be copied in the same folder when compiling. 
https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/179594_10150982737360698_1827200234_n.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently in Linux and can't test with Safari, but still will post the answer...

Try to do in [**this way**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/e7qbS/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image-container"></div>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var container = document.getElementById('image-container'),
    image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="img/gauge.png" width="122" height="127"/><g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)"><circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/></g><text id="value" x="35" y="103" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text></svg>';
container.appendChild(image);
​
```

**UPDATE #1 - data URI encoding:**

The usage of unencoded data URI might be failed in IE 8 and 9.

So you can determine the browser using `navigator.userAgent` and if it's IE >= 8,
then [encode the string to Base64](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html) before assigning it as value of `image.src`.

**UPDATE #2 - using `object` tag:**

```
var container = document.getElementById('image-container'),
    imageObject = document.createElement('object');
imageObject.type = 'image/svg+xml';
imageObject.data = 'data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="img/gauge.png" width="122" height="127"/><g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)"><circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/></g><text id="value" x="35" y="103" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text></svg>';
container.appendChild(imageObject);
```

​You can set either the data URI or direct link to .svg file location.

[**`object` DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/e7qbS/1/)

**UPDATE #3 - CSS approach:**

```
var container = document.getElementById('image-container');
container.style.width = '100px';
container.style.height = '100px';
container.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="img/gauge.png" width="122" height="127"/><g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)"><circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/></g><text id="value" x="35" y="103" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text></svg>\')';

​
```

[**DEMO of CSS approach**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/e7qbS/4/)

**UPDATE #4 - MIME type:**

Comment by [UnderDog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319819/underdog):

> I changed the datatype, and it worked.. but additionally I also had to
>   configure web.config file to add this:

`<staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" /></staticContent>`

The server should send correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: As a side note, when I open that URL in Chrome, two pencils (?) are drawed, but on refresh, one disappears...

Comment: That's strange. I'm seeing only one pencil in Chrome.

Comment: Actually, the image needs to be attached with "my_object" else it wont be displayed. So, I tried doing this this.my_object.setAttribute('image', image);
but it still doesn't work (not even on firefox now). I tried declaring the file in css, and then access it like this.my_object.setAttribute('class', 'SVGimage');
but no luck

Comment: I can try, but I dont know how that will help. my_object is an object, and the way it will put the image on background will be with setAttribute or innerHTMl, initializing directly to image source doesnt seem right.

Comment: Let's clarify, what do you mean saying "my_object is an object"? the variable `my_object` is a reference to HTMLElement `object`? If yes, then my second update in answer could help.

Comment: my_object is an element, which will be inserted in the parent like this, this.m_parent.insert(this.my_object)..

Comment: I am sorry I should have been more clear when I mentioned its an element. this.my_object = new Element('svg');

Comment: So the StackOverflow answer you referred to is saying clear that 'svg' element can't be embedded itself, but you have to use either `embed`, `object` or `iframe` element to do this.

Comment: I did that. Like I used embed.. this.my_object = new Element('embed');
this.my_object.setAttribute("src","img/gauge.svg");  Is this not the way?

Comment: Did you see my example from my "UPDATE #2"? It's different. You should set `data` attribute instead of `src`. And yes, it can be a link to image file location. Also you have to set the `type` attribute as I showed in my example.

Comment: I changed the datatype, and it worked.. but additionally I also had to configure web.config file to add this <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

Comment: Can you provide help in one more thing.. Now I need to access one element of svg file.. You can see above. It is called 'needle'. can i access it now? Previously, I was able to access it, since svg was inline..

Comment: Create a div element in memory, insert svg markup into it. Retrieve `#needle`, modify it. Get div's innerHTML, set new `object.data`.

Comment: div element with "memory"? can you explain with code, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Can you create a separate question for this?

Comment: Also, if you could add mime thing in your answer, I can accept it. :)