# SVG Linear gradient doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, safari, svg, linear-gradients

I've got an SVG object that contains a linear gradient embedded directly in a document. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari nothing is rendered. If I create the SVG as a file and embed it using the Object tag, it works fine in Safari. Other shapes and fills work, it's just linear gradient that doesn't work. I guess I could use the object, but I'd prefer to embed the SVG directly.

I've create a demo here (works in Chrome, not Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/sjKbN/

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117380/doctype-problem-displaying-svg-with-safari) which suggests setting the content type to `application/xhtml+xml`, but this in itself seems to cause other problems.

Just wondering if anyone had come across any other fixes or ideas to get this working.

Comment: The gradient works in the nightly webkit build version of safari (available for download http://nightly.webkit.org/ ) so there is a good chance it will work in a future released version of safari.

Comment: Ahh that's awesome, glad to see they've fixed it. Cheers for the tip!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your gradient will work in Safari if you wrap a `defs` tag around it:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
 <defs>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="5.6665" y1="149.5" x2="293.333" y2="149.5">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFF33B"/>
    <stop  offset="0.0595" style="stop-color:#FFE029"/>
    <stop  offset="0.1303" style="stop-color:#FFD218"/>
    <stop  offset="0.2032" style="stop-color:#FEC90F"/>
    <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#FDC70C"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6685" style="stop-color:#F3903F"/>
    <stop  offset="0.8876" style="stop-color:#ED683C"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#E93E3A"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="5.667" y="5.333" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" width="287.667" height="288.333"/>
</svg>
```

​It seems that wrapping your references in `defs` is encouraged but not obligatory [according to spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DefsElement). So this is a bug in Safari.

Comment: I wish I could give more upvotes for this answer, this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: still a problem with url using <base href="/" />

Answer (score 24):

About Alpha : It seems that Safari (7 at this moment) does not cover SVG color alpha channel, use stop opacity attribute. it works fine!

```
<stop stop-color="rgba(x,y,z,0.5)"> //safari does not work
<stop stop-color="rgb(x,y,z)" stop-opacity="0.5"> //ok
```

Comment: The code in the question does not use rgba colours, so it's not an answer to this particular question.

Comment: Wrong Sir Longson! First searching for the defect on linear gradient that did not work as same in safari than other browser, I saw this post first. Second, The topic is related to the safari different behaviour of linear gradient. Alpha channel is a part of this global topic :"SVG Linear gradient doesn't work in Safari"

Comment: @Sebastien, great answer. It is definitely relevant to have it here! Thank you

Comment: Perfect! you saved my acc :')). here is my code: `{offset: "100%", color: "rgb(130,130,130)", opacity:"0"}` for data and `.attr("stop-opacity", function(d) { return d.opacity; });    ` when you append `stop`. Cheers.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer was not the solution for me.

My problem was the presence of a `<base href="/" />` tag in my index file. Simply removing it solved the problem for me.

If you cannot remove it, probably some workaround already exist: found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/leonderijke/c5cf7c5b2e424c0061d2) but I did not tested it.

**Update**

Simply removing the href broke the child routing of my angular app, the proper workaround is to prepend to the linearGradient id with the page relative location. I wrapped the logic in a method like this:

```
get svgFill(): string {
  return `url(${this.location.path()}#${this.gradientId}) white`;
}
```

Comment: You can use:
`window.location.pathname`

as the prefix.

Example:
`url(${window.location.pathname}#${this.gradientId}) white`

Comment: @OfekA That will break if there are query parameters: `http://example.com/page.html?arg=val`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, all id's (not only `<linear gradient>`) need to be UNIQUE for all SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles too making an inline SVG with a linear gradient work. The designer had put a `-` in the id of the `<linearGradient`. The solution was as simple as removing it.

```
<linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
...
<path fill="url(#linear-gradient)" d="..."/>
```

with

```
<linearGradient id="lineargradient">
...
<path fill="url(#lineargradient)" d="..."/>
```