# Inline SVG Gradient turns Black in Opera

Tags: safari, svg, extjs4, opera, gradient

I have a similar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303740/svg-linear-gradient-doesnt-work-in-safari/11310511#11310511) and prepared an example based on that issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxhyv/

Every browser handles this fine except Safari and Opera. In Opera if you first click on 
"Run" the SVG is rendered as a Black Box. After a click on "Update" the SVG is rendered 
correctly. 
In our application we use it in ExtJS 4.1.1 setting the html code of a panel directly with

```
html = '<svg id="foo" > .... </svg>';
this.update(html);
```

where html is simply the String containing the svg.

It works fine except the gradients in the two browsers which give me a black shape then.
For various reasons (event handling, manipulation of the IDs etc.) it has to be an inline SVG to get event listeners running:

```
listeners : {

    click : {
        element : 'el',
        fn : function(a, b, c, d) {
            var svgElement = b;
[...]
```

I am completely out of ideas now and very grateful for all suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, now reported as Opera bug CORE-49122.

Comment: Good to know... so in Safari it is also a bug that should be reported?

Comment: your fiddle link is working fine in my opera. My version is 
`Version: 18.0.1284.68`
`Update stream: Stable`
`System: Windows 7 64-bit (WoW64)`