# Linear gradients, filters, masks, clip-paths in SVGs not showing in iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, svg, ionic4

**Background**

I've got a somewhat complex gradient needs in my first Ionic4 PWA (thanks to a talented designer who is ALSO new to PWAs).

Many SVG custom icons are calling many different linear-gradient's through `fill:url(#the-gradient);` throughout our .scss files. Some of these icons have 9 states (grey, 7 colors, rainbow)

Additionally, these gradients use CSS variables in the stops to further customize the gradients based on themes. These gradients are being stored currently in index.html so that all icons can access them.

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="width:0;height:0;position:absolute;">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="default-icon-graydient" x1="0" x2="0" ,="" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--gratiu-dark-grey)"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--gratiu-ml-grey)"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="select-icon-gradient" x1="0" x2="0" ,="" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--gratiu-current-color)"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="var(--gratiu-current-color)"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--gratiu-next-color)"/>
      </linearGradient>
<!--and many, many more...-->
    </defs>
</svg>
```

This system works perfectly on android and on desktop - on iOS however, whether safari or chrome, ***the icons do not appear.***

**Things I've tried:**

- First I added a backup solid color to the fills eg. `fill:
  url(#select-icon-gradient) var(--gratiu-current-color);` this works to keep it functional,
  but these gradients are vital bits of information for our users and
  they need to be able to see them, not just flat colors
- I then tried absolutely linking to the index.html `fill: url('http://localhost:8100/index.html#select-icon-gradient');` but this didn't work anywhere
- I then tried storing the SVG code in an external SVG, and linking to that absolutely `fill: url('http://localhost:8100/app/assets/img/gradients.svg#select-icon-gradient');` still didn't work
- I tried moving the gradients back into each SVG file rather than linking to an external files for them Still didn't work.
- I thought I was really smart, when I made divs with CSS gradients in their `background` property, but when it came time to call a path to use for `clip-path: url(#the-path)`, I ran into the same problem as the gradients themselves. Absolutely linking didn't work. Having the clipPath AND the CSS inline on the same page as the icon worked on desktop, but not iOS.
- As an aside, I also noticed during this process the same issue with applying an SVG filter (drop shadow). I was able to locate a work around where I can use a containing div and apply a CSS filter on it...but it's not ideal.

**The current options I feel I have are:**

- Replace every single icon style ever with PNGs and use switch cases and if statements to call the appropriate ones which will need to change on the fly.
- Create a single SVG for each icon with a rasterized version of each gradient, use CSS to show/hide each individual image.

Obviously a single PNG is lighter weight than a big ol stuffed SVG...but the benefit to the SVG is it would load once and be done with it.

**To the questions:**

- Is there something I haven't tried yet? Anything I've overlooked?
- Are SVGs or PNGs better in PWAs anyway?
- Why is this so flipping hard?

Comment: I was facing the same problem, and got it solved by following advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53579924/1323800.