# Safari 6 svg tag use issues

Tags: svg, safari, safari6

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/xkpeD/

or just

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="pink" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  <use xlink:href="#:example" x="20" y="20"/>
  <defs>
    <circle id=":example" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="pink" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  </defs>
</svg>​
```

It displays ok in all browsers (IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari 5.1), but in new Safari 6 only 1 circle is rendered. Seems that all <use> tags doesn't rendered in Safari 6.

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried putting the <defs> section before the <use> element?

Comment: See the last comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514248/svg-use-elements-in-chrome-not-displayed?rq=1. If they haven't fixed this yet, you can try to replace <use ... /> with <use ...></use> as a quick workaround.

Comment: Thanks, sam! Unfortunately this is still an issue in 6.0.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sam.kozin's answer worked for me. Just so that this answer actually has visibility.

Replace <use ... /> with <use ...></use>

So:

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="pink" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  <use xlink:href="#:example" x="20" y="20"></use>
  <defs>
    <circle id=":example" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="pink" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  </defs>
</svg>​
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, OP. I solved it by doing 2 steps

1. Separated the `<use>` and the `<defs>` into 2 different `<svg>`'s (not sure if this step is necessary, also had to do it for other reasons). Side note, if an `<svg>` only has `<defs>`, you can use `style="display: none;"` to make it not take space in the layout.
2. Moved the `<svg>` containing the `<defs>` ABOVE the `<svg>` containing the `<use>` in my HTML. This step is crucial.

Hope this helps. Necessary and working for Safari Version 7.1.2 as of today, 12/19/14

Comment: BIG UPVOTE for moving `<svg>` w/ `<defs>` ABOVE the `<svg>` with `<use>`!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `<use href="">` that was rendering without issues in Firefox / Chrome, but not in Safari. So I had to change to `<use xlink:href="">` and this fixed my rendering issues in Safari.

Comment: If You set the attribute with **JavaScript**, it works only by using `useElem.setAttributeNS ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#your-href');`. Using the following will fail, even if it looks correct in the *Inspector*: `useElem.setAttribute ('xlink:href', '#your-href');`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using correct http content-type header and serving your document as valid XML. More info in this similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117380/doctype-problem-displaying-svg-with-safari).